# grouping rows of pandas dataframe inside a loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, group-by

I have the below dataframe test and my objective is to check if the time period repeats and if it repeats I want to group by and take a mean of repeated time rows

[image: my input data]

My desired output will be like

[image]

I have tried the below code

> ```
> for i in range(len(test)-1):
>     if test['time'][i] == test['time'][i+1]:
>
>         test[i:i+1].groupby('time').mean().reset_index()
>     else:
>
>         break
> ```

But its not working as desired. Will appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: It's just `df.groupby('time', as_index=False).mean()`

Comment: When you say not working as desired, what is it doing? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @coldspeed , Got it, I don't even have to run the loop. Thanks